# insertBefore is duplicating content

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/072uwd1k/

I'm trying to change the number location to be placed above text, using `insertBefore` does just that but it's duplicating it for the number of `div`s in there.

```
<div class="box-wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <p class="text">ABC</p>
    <p class="num">123</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p class="text">ABC</p>
    <p class="num">123</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

> $('.num').insertBefore('.text');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you have more classes `num` you need to use `.each()` and `.prev()` to get the previous .text element

```js
$('.num').each(function(){
  $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev('.text'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <p class="text">ABC</p>
    <p class="num">123</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <p class="text">ABC</p>
    <p class="num">123</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

> So what you need is  `.each()` to loop through `.num` elements ..
>   `$(this)` to get spacific `.num` element and `$(this).prev('.text')`
>   to select the previous `.text`

Comment: you're totally welcome @jimmyholy2  .. Have a great day :)